# Put parceable in android intent uri

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I am trying to put a parceable in an Android intent, and converting the intent to URI.

My problem is that the parceable does not show up on the URI.

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.action.QRCODE_SCANNED");
intent.putExtra(CHECKOUT_INFO, data);

String finaldata = Uri.encode(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME), "iso-8859-15");
```

What is the problem?
Should I avoid passing parceables through URI?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that you are trying to Uri encode an already Uri encoded string.

As per the Intent class documentation for the toUri() method:

> Convert this Intent into a String holding a URI representation of it. The returned URI string has been properly URI encoded, so it can be used with **Uri.parse(String)**. The URI contains the Intent's data as the base URI, with an additional fragment describing the action, categories, type, flags, package, component, and extras.

So try:

```
String finaldata = Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was not the issue, as when I pass the values one by one instead of a parceable it works fine.

Comment: Did you figure it out?